# Unable to install libsasl2-devel on Amazon Linux 2 machine

Tags: linux, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pip, amazon-linux-2

I am running Ansible playbook and trying to install OS dependencies packages for python. I am trying to run the following:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ libffi-devel python-devel python-pip python-wheel openssl-devel libsasl2-devel openldap-devel
```

However, it fails at installing libsasl2-devel with the message:
`"No package matching 'libsasl2-devel' found available, installed or updated"`

All my instances are Amazon Linux 2 machines. Is there any alternative package for this? I tried to look into this but I found solutions for Ubuntu only.

Comment: Same problem. As a possibly helpful note, Ami installs libsals3 instead of 2, which is supposed to fully backwards compatible. However, it doesn't solve the dependency requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work in a series of steps. Its a yum issue after other databases are installed and not cleaned up before installing mysql

clear sasl first: `sudo yum remove cyrus-sasl`

if you have installed maria, there will be conflicts, remove that as well
`sudo yum remove mariadb mariadb-server mariadb-libs`

take note of anything uninstalled by this to re-add later. If this is too much, you can take a risk and not remove sasl, but it might not reset the availability of the package.

Start here to clean up the dependency issues: https://serverfault.com/questions/873955/how-solve-mysql-5-7-dependency  follow the command given by clean all as `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*`

This can possibly resolve your issues right there, if not continue the installation below.

delete all data left in /var/lib/mysql/ or you may have upgrade issues.

resinstall sasl:
`sudo yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-devel`  and any other packages removed above.

Establish mysql5.7 with the yum services.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall -y mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
sudo yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
sudo yum repolist enabled | grep mysql
sudo yum install -y mysql-community-common mysql-community-libs mysql-community-server mysql-community-client
```

if that doesn't work, re-clear the yum cache again and re-run `sudo yum install -y mysql-community-server`

if that works, then

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

IF the /var/lib/mysql is empty, it will have created a temporary password in the /var/log/mysqld.log (use sudo to read)

run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and establish your real password and security settings.

now you should have access via `mysql -u root -p`